# Search for str in a column and create a new list of items

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, dataframe

I have a dataframe train with a column called "Name". My goal is to search the name column for the str "Doc" in it. My end goal is to add a new column to my dataframe called "Doctor". The values in the column will be 1 or 0. If the name in the column contains the str "Doc", the value in the Doctor column should be 1. If it does not contain "Doc", then the value in the Doctor column should be 0.

This is the code I have so far. I am trying to create a list of #'s that I can then add into the Doctor column.

```
temp_list = []
for i in train:
    if i in train[train["Name"].str.contains("Doc")]:
        temp_list.append("1")
    else:
        temp_list.append("0")
```

After running this function, it is returning a list of 1's but no 0's

```
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
temp_list = []
for word in train["Name"]:
  temp_list.append('1') if 'Doc' in word else temp_list.append('0')
```